# While sending a service request (PHP Service) from Flex application, it is executing multiple service request to server. How can we avoid first call?

Tags: apache-flex

While sending a service request (PHP Service) from Adobe Flex application , it is calling multiple service request to server. How can we avoid first call ?

Please help me to resolve it.

First one is a blank service with operation => 5. 
We can show blank service call via firebug (Browser -> Developer tool)

Sample Flex Code :

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <s:RemoteObject id="CustomerRo" destination="customerService" endpoint="<SERVER URL>"
                    showBusyCursor="false" source="customerService" concurrency="single" >
        <s:method name="customerLogin" fault=""
                  result="method1_resultHandler(event)"  />
    </s:RemoteObject> 
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button click="button1_clickHandler(event)" label="Send" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to do the following changes in flex application for avoid duplicate call from every request

1. Add 'services-config.xml" to the application folder. (Ref : https://gist.github.com/hui/268372 )
2. Add  configuration file path to Flex compiler, (Project->Properties->Flex Compiler)
          Example :  -locale en_US -services "C:\Location/services-config.xml"
3. Change this attribute in code base of each modules

From : < s:RemoteObject id="CustomerRo" destination="customerService" endpoint="< SERVER URL >" showBusyCursor="false" source="customerService" concurrency="single" >

To : < s:RemoteObject id="CustomerRo" destination="amfora" showBusyCursor="false" source="customerService" concurrency="single" >

[Note : Destination should be equal to < destination id="amfora" > in 'services-config.xml" ]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 5 is part of the AMF protocol and signals that a command operation is the next operation that should be expected by the server.